# How can I programmatically call an IBAction for UISwitch if the switch will be changing on its own?

Tags: objective-c, methods, ibaction, uiswitch

Is there a way to programmatically call a switch that changes to on/off on its own based off an external device reading voltage levels and sending data to the iPod Touch? (5 volts = switch is on, less than 5 = switch is off)

Comment: switch.on = YES; that would change it to On.

Comment: No I mean, is there a way to listen for when it does turn on; for instance I have switch.on being called within an update method based on the voltage. But how do I tell the IBAction which sender turned on? sorry for my lack of clarity.

Comment: In terms of usability, you should allow the user to pick the on/off state, and if there's something externally that doesn't allow switching it, disable the switch rather than switching it on/off. Say, as a user, I want to keep the thing on/off regardless of the external conditions.

Comment: The user can control the switch... via plugging in electrical devices to the external device that is connected to the ipod. For instance the user connects the ipod to the electrical-pulse reading device, and the electrical pulse reading device reads a pulse for switch 0; then turns switch 0 on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering your comment, this should be what you want:

```
[yourSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchStateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

And then, the actual method:

```
-(void)switchStateChanged:(UISwitch*)thisSwitch{
    // code
}
```

Comment: yes! Thank you, this is precisely what I was wondering about.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to programmatically call a switch that changes to
>   on/off on its own based off an external device reading voltage levels
>   and sending data to the iPod Touch? (5 volts = switch is on, less than
>   5 = switch is off)

Yes, you can of course set the `on` property of the switch to either YES or NO. For example, if your view controller has an outlet called `theSwitch`, it could set the switch thus:

```
self.theSwitch.on = YES;
```

That said, you really *shouldn't* use a standard switch that way. Switches are user controls, not displays. If the user sees a switch, they'll expect to be able to change it, and for the most part they won't expect the switch to change state by itself. It would be much better to create some sort of indicator that looks different so that you don't confuse your users.

Also, I think there's a paragraph in the App Store submission guidelines about not using Apple UI elements in unexpected ways. If you're planning on publishing your app in the app store, you may risk having it rejected on this basis.

One simple solution would be to use a UISwitch, but set the `onImage` and `offImage` properties to your own images, so that the switch doesn't look like something the user expects to control.

**Update:** From your comment, it sounds like you only want to know when the switch changes. The *right* answer here (IMO) is that your update method shouldn't change the switch directly, but should instead set some value in the data model. The view controller that manages the view containing the switch could then observe the model using key value observing and adjust the switch's value accordingly, as well as call the switch's action.

Comment: I think my question is being misconstrued; I mean I want to call anIBAction WHEN the switch.on happens... refer to my other comment and I understand switches aren't meant to normally be this way but there is a very specific way for having it set this way.

Comment: Like stated, the application has already been published and approved; it's an update on the same premise and this has already been approved. The application has one very specific use.